# Problem with set the path for JAVA_HOME on mac?

Tags: java, macos, path

I am using a mac, and I have installed java on it, but I am having a problem with setting the path for JAVA_HOME.

Here are the three ways I tried, but none of these worked, btw, one of the path is for python:

```
export PATH=${PATH}:/usr/local/mysql/bin/:JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home)

export PATH=${PATH}:/usr/local/mysql/bin/
export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home)

export PATH=${PATH}:/usr/local/mysql/bin/
export JAVA_HOME=`/usr/libexec/java_home -v 13.0.1`
```

Here is where my java installed:

```
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-13.0.1.jdk/Contents/Home
```

I tried using the above three methods, but when I typed `echo $JAVA_HOME`, still nothing was shown.

Does anyone know what could be wrong? Any suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: are you setting it in terminal or script ?

Comment: Yes, I was doing it on the terminal in a file named .bash_profile

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so in case someone didn't read all the comments. We do need to do the `source .bash_profile` to apply the new changes. Thanks for all the comments and suggestions. Appreciated it.

Answer (score 0):

To set the JAVA_HOME:

```
export JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-13.0.1.jdk/Contents/Home
```

And then run `echo $JAVA_HOME` on Terminal to confirm the path.

Note that this sets `JAVA_HOME` only for the current session. If you want it to persist, you will have to add that command to your `~/.profile` or `~/.bash_profile` file and then open a new terminal window for it to work.

Update: And activate your changes with `source .bash_profile` as @skryvets points out.

Comment: Yes, I was doing it on the terminal in a file called .bash_profile

Comment: It works just doing it on the terminal, but it doesn't work if I put the command in the .bash_profile file. Could it be that because I have the export PATH=${PATH}:/usr/local/mysql/bin/  before it?

Comment: There should not be a problem with having the PATH set before the JAVA_HOME if both commands are in different lines in the `.bash_profile` file. Have you opened another terminal to check it? If you edit the bash_profile it won't load the changes until you open a new terminal

Comment: After you save your changes in ‘.bash_profile’ you have to execute ‘source’ command on it to apply new changes - ‘source .bash_profile’. Otherwise, newly saved changes will not be applied. Good luck.

Comment: Oh yeah, you are right. It works now. We do need to try the "source .bash_profile".